# How to submit a form multiple times (asp.net core razor)

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to create a form that can be submitted multiple times with different information, while retaining a common value in one field.

I have a list view from a SQL table in ASP.NET Core Razor that is a list of construction projects.  For each row in the list I have a link that goes to a "create" template page where users can create a bid entry for the project which is stored in a different table.  The Project Number is assigned to a route value (asp-route-Number = "*the project number from the previous list*")and populates a hidden field in the "create new bid" form.

Using the default code for the razor page, everything works great.  You click submit and are taken back to the list of projects.

What I want to do is have another option on the "create new bid" form that will allow you to save and enter another bid for the same project.  I created another button and handler to do this but I am stuck on actually implementing it.  If I use return Page() the form posts and the page is returned with route data intact, but the text fields still contain the previous data and the drop-down list is empty.  If I use return RedirectToPage(CreateNewBid, Route data) the form posts but the route data does not seem to be passed along and creates a null value error.

This is the link from the Projects list (inside the foreach table), which takes you to the "Create Bid" form and works fine.

```
<a asp-page="CreateBid" asp-route-Number="@item.ProjectNumber" asp-route-opwid="@item.Id">New Bid</a>
```

The Create Bid form has the following to submit and create another entry

```
int num = int.Parse(Request.Query["Number"]);
int idnum = int.Parse(Request.Query["opwid"]); 

<input type="submit" value="Save and enter another" 
                   asp-page-handler="Another" asp-route-opwid="@idnum" 
                   asp-route-Number="@num" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

And the handler:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAnotherAsync(int Number, int opwid)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.OpwBids.Add(OpwBids);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Page();
            //return RedirectToPage("./CreateBid", (Number == num, opwid == idnum));
        }
```

I have also tried several things in the route parameters (as opposed to using the variables) in the "Redirect to Page" and nothing seems to work.

Is there an easier way, or am I just missing something?

This is the cshtml file:

```
@page 
@model Authorization_AD.Pages.GenSvc.BidEntry.CreateBidModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateBid";
}

@{ int num = int.Parse(Request.Query["Number"]);
   int idnum = int.Parse(Request.Query["opwid"]);       
 }

<h1>Create Bid</h1>

<h4>OPW number @num</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="OpwBids.OpwProject" value="@idnum" hidden class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OpwBids.OpeningDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OpwBids.OpeningDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OpwBids.OpeningDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OpwBids.Contractor" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="OpwBids.Contractor" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Contractor">
                    <option disabled selected>--- SELECT ---</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OpwBids.BidAmount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OpwBids.BidAmount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OpwBids.BidAmount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save and enter another" 
                       asp-page-handler="Another" asp-route-opwid="@idnum" 
                       asp-route-Number="@num" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Save and return to list" asp-page-handler="Done" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

This is the C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Authorization_AD.Models;

namespace Authorization_AD.Pages.GenSvc.BidEntry
{
    public class CreateBidModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Authorization_AD.Models.OPWContext _context;

        public CreateBidModel(Authorization_AD.Models.OPWContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
        ViewData["Contractor"] = new SelectList(_context.Contractors, "Id", "ContractorName");
        ViewData["OpwProject"] = new SelectList(_context.MainProjectsListing, "Id", "ProjectNumber");
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public OpwBids OpwBids { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDoneAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.OpwBids.Add(OpwBids);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAnotherAsync(int Number, int opwid)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.OpwBids.Add(OpwBids);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Page();
            //return RedirectToPage("./CreateBid", (Number == OpwBids.OpwProjectNavigation.ProjectNumber, opwid == OpwBids.OpwProject));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you talk about your specific needs? What do you need to achieve? Create multiple OpwBids on the Create page?

Comment: If you can, you can post the code of your Create page.

Comment: What I want is a form with two buttons at the bottom.  One is "Save and quit" the other is "Save and create another" which creates the DB record, reloads the same form and remembers the project number which is pre-populated into a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property to your page that will be used to bind the value of the clicked button.

```
public class CreateBidModel : PageModel {

    //...

    //Add this property to your page.
    [BindProperty]
    public string Button {get;set;}
    
    public void OnGet(int number,string opwid){
        //Set the number and opwid to the target properties
    }
    
    public Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(){
        
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.OpwBids.Add(OpwBids);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if(Button == "finish"){
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
        else {
            return RedirectToPage("./CreateBid", (Number == OpwBids.OpwProjectNavigation.ProjectNumber, opwid == OpwBids.OpwProject));
        }
    }
}
```

To the view you need to add two buttons that have the same name and that value will be mapped to the Button property.

```
<form method="post">
... Other content goes here

    <button name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Button)" value="another">Create another</button>
    <button name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Button)" value="finish">Finish</button>
</form>
```

The value of the clicked button will be parsed to the Button property of the Pagemodel. Based on the value you can decide how to further handle the response of the request (Finish / Create another one in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help.  I got it to do what I want by adding the following to the "OnPostAnotherAsync" task:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAnotherAsync(int Number, int opwid)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.OpwBids.Add(OpwBids);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        ViewData["Contractor"] = new SelectList(_context.Contractors, "Id", "ContractorName");
        ModelState.SetModelValue("OpwBids.BidAmount", new ValueProviderResult(string.Empty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        ModelState.SetModelValue("OpwBids.Contractor", new ValueProviderResult(string.Empty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        
        return Page();
     }
```

After the "Save Changes" I needed to re-load the view data for the "Contractor" drop down list. Then it was just a matter of clearing the form fields before returning the page.